# Do graphs slow down my calculation speed in a large excel file?

Tags: vba, excel, graph

I am working with a huge excel file that is updated with a set of macros. In the excel file there are also a large number of graphs to ensure easy output checks.

However, when I re-calculate the workbook it is extremely slow.

My question is: Do these graphs contribute to slowing down the calculation of the model? If so, is there a quick VBA way to only update graphs at the end of the overall calculation?

Comment: It takes processor time (or "calculation power") to perform each calculation in your workbook, and then update the formatting and/or conditional formatting in each cell as necessary, and then to draw the graphics for the chart means numerous other calculations need to be done. (All this while sharing the processor time with any other open applications or running processes. Everything adds up. If multiple charts refer to the same data, they should be setup to share the data source instead of each calculating separately.

Comment: Also, if you're calculating within a VBA procedure, then perhaps you should switch the workbook to manual calculation and disable [the `Application.ScreenUpdating` property](https://docs.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating) at the beginning of the procedure, re-enabling at the end.  This is a somewhat vague solution, for a very vague question. Check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) and also see "[ask]" and **how to create a [mcve]**. More tips from the sites' top user [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: This information is not enough to answer your question , Do you have array formulas , lookups in your sheets ? what happens when you delete the graphs and recalculate ?what happens when you remove lookups and recalculate ?you need to try different approaches to zero in the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your workbook this is hard to answer.

Most likely, it is not the charts (is that what you call "graphs") that are slowing down the recalc, but inefficient formulas.

Check the chart data sources. If they point to worksheet cells, then all is good. If they point to named ranges / named formulas, then check what these formulas are.

Recalculation is affected by

- volatile formulas like Today(), Now(), Indirect(), Offset() and a few others
- inefficient formulas that needlessly repeat calculations that have already been performed, typically done in running totals

And example of this would be

=Sum(A$1:A2) copied down, like in this screenshot

[image]

In each row, the calculation starts in row 1 and goes down to the current row. This is a waste of effort.

A much more efficient formula is in column C, where just the value from the row above is added to the value of the current row.

```
=SUM(C1,A2)
```

[image]

These details can make a heck of a difference.

For more information you may want to refer to Charles Williams' site http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecrets.htm and the pages linked from there.

It's a complex subject and can probably not be addressed in a simple answer to a seemingly simple question.